# Prove: For all sets A,B,C,D subsets of universal set U. If A ∪ B = C ∪ D = U, then B ∩ C ≠ ∅ or A ∪ D = U

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have no real idea of how to start this proof. I can't really see a way to parse the given info other than that the part with A  ∪ B = C ∪ D = U are subsets of each other, but I can't see how the statement will allow you to separate the A,B or C,D from each other to get B ∩ C ≠ ∅ or A ∪ D = U.

Any help for at least finding a starting point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $B\cap C=\phi$ and $A\cup D\neq U$, then: $$(A\cup B)\cap(C\cup D) = (A\cap C)\cup(A\cap D)\cup (B\cap C)\cup(B\cap D) = (A\cap C)\cup(A\cap D)\cup(B\cap D)$$ and our goal is to prove that we will never have that this set is $U$ (Because that would mean that all three sets, $ (A\cup B),\ (C\cup D)$ and $U$ are equal).

As $A\cup D\neq U$, there exists $x\in U$ that isn't in $A$ or in $D$. Then, $x$ doesn't belong to any of the sets $(A\cap C),\ (A\cap D)$ or $(B\cap D)$, thus, it can't be in $(A\cup B)\cap(C\cup D)$, so that set can't be $U$.

Comment: Yup I just figured it out right as you posted this, appreciate the help, thanks